# Updating Full Calendar Day At Midnight

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

```
    //Reset At Midnight
function resetAtMidnight() {
    var now = new Date();
    var night = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate() + 1, // the next day, ...
        0, 0, 0 // ...at 00:00:00 hours
    );
    var msToMidnight = night.getTime() - now.getTime();

    setTimeout(function() {
        reset();              //      <-- This is the function being called at midnight.
        resetAtMidnight();    //      Then, reset again next midnight.
    }, msToMidnight);
}


function reset() {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
}
```

I am trying to have FullCalendar.js update the current day everyday at midnight. I pulled this reset snippet from another post on here - but the reset function does not seem to execute.

Comment: Hi John, it's unclear what you're asking here, and you seem to be mixing libraries together (is this a jQuery question?). Maybe a more complete example of what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help other users understand your question.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and why? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided full detail so I don't know what exactly you need but following code might help you to solve your issue.

You can check midnight quite easily using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. 
Following code was taken from another post [Best Way to detect midnight and reset data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387052/best-way-to-detect-midnight-and-reset-data)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var midnight = "0:00:00";
  var now = null;

  setInterval(function() {
    now = moment().format("H:mm:ss");
    if (now === midnight) {
      alert('reset() function here');
    }
    $("#time").text(now);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<code id="time"></code>
```

Fullcontrol:

You can either use [rerenderEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/rerenderEvents) or [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/refetchEvents) as per your requirement. So it will be something like this

```
function reset(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
OR

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
}
```

If you want to re-draw the fullcontrol then here is another informative post '[re-draw fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324311/re-draw-fullcalendar-on-the-fly)'

As post suggested you can do

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```